# Linking between two https sites - add referrer so it shows up in Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, html, https, google-analytics

So pretty sure this is a very simple question but I can't seem to find an answer for it:

I have two https sites, Site A and Site B. I have a link from Site A to Site B and want to see how many people are following that link by looking at the traffic sources of Site B in Google Analytics.

How would I add a referrer so that when users click on a link I don't see 'Traffic Sources -> Direct' in Site B's analytics report?

All I'm doing is adding a link in site A:

```
<a href="LINK_TO_SITE_B" target="_blank">
```

Comment: `Referer` header should be sent normally between two HTTPS sites. Have you checked that it's the header that is not being sent rather than analytics somehow hiding HTTPS referer info?

Answer (score 0):

I think the proper way would be to include [utm campaign tags.](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en) This will allow you to add more information (the url builder has pretty good documentation, I don't think I need to repeat that here).

However even between https pages you should see AFAIK a referring url - the only restriction I know if is with mixed content (i.e that "[Clients SHOULD NOT include a Referer header field in a (non-secure) HTTP request if the referring page was transferred with a secure protocol](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec15.html#sec15.1.3)."). Maybe you have accidentally added both domains to the referrals exclusion list (this is necessary only for cross domain tracking) ?